# Typescript error on using array that gets elements in loop

Tags: typescript

A basic use-case that illustrates what I'm doing:

```js
class Foo {
  public constructor(arg1: number, arg2: number) {
    console.log(arg1);
    console.log(arg2);
  }
}

function foo(test: number): number[] {
  let args: number[] = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    args.push(i);
  }
  if (args.length !== 2) {
    throw new Error('Invalid argument length');
  }
  return new Foo(...args);
}

console.log(foo(1));
```

When trying to run this, I get:

```
error TS2556: Expected 2 arguments, but got 0 or more.

16   return new Foo(...args);
```

Which I'm absolutely unable sure where to go to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the error you are getting :

```
class Foo {
  public constructor(arg1: number, arg2: number) {
  }
}

declare let args: number[];
new Foo(...args); // expected 2 but got 0 or more.
```

## why

Because `number[]` can be an array of length `0` or more than 2. So it doesn't match `[number,number]` i.e. an array of exactly length 2.

## Fix

Either annotate as a tupple `[number,number]`:

```
declare let args: [number,number];
new Foo(...args); // Ok
```

Or get the values from the array your self:

```
new Foo(args[0],args[1]);
```

Comment: So if I have some number of different classes that all take a variable amount of arguments, there's no real way to use variable expansion here for the arguments as I'd always have to annotate it as a tuple of the appropriate length?

Comment: Or annotate as `any`. It is *okay* to use in a controlled manner when you want to do localized magic coding 

Comment: Casting or annotating as `any` doesn't seem to make a difference. I guess casting to a tuple of a specific length is the only way, other than using `Reflect.construct()` (which doesn't work in IE).

Comment: I figured it out—you can cast the class itself to any: `new (Foo as any)(...args);`